# Problem running erratic_robot

Tags: ros, erratic, erratic-gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have downloaded the possible tools to run the erractic_robot in gazebo but when I try to roslaunch (roslaunch erratic_description erratic_empty_world.launch) it, it gives me an error:

[erratic_description] is not a package or launch file name

I have the erractic_description and I can look into the folder that the roslaunch is trying to access but it keeps denying me.

Any help is MUCH appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29078/problem-running-erratic_robot./) by [njavia66](https://answers.ros.org/users/1906/njavia66/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2012-03-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It won't find the package unless the package is on your [ROS_PACKAGE_PATH](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/EnvironmentVariables#ROS_PACKAGE_PATH)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0